# BCFIPS - org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: expected this got that

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle, fips

My code is failing at the point when it tries to ensure there is FIPS DRBG present

```
CryptoServicesRegistrar.setSecureRandom(
   FipsDRBG.SHA512_HMAC.fromEntropySource(
      new BasicEntropySourceProvider(new SecureRandom(), true))
      .build(null, true)
);
```

The error that I get is

org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: expected [d68017e6f45512a51a862c77e4fa2348d0d24d816bc3f76fcf30375052216e86] got [0743af5630f08660b4b0dc5bc46bbe441e3341e27cbb6794cd15b1d14ce98d4e]\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.moveToErrorStatus(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.checksumValidate(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.getDefaultMode(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.internal.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.useStrict(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.internal.encodings.PKCS1Encoding.(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.RsaDigestSigner.(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsRSA$4.evaluate(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.SelfTestExecutor.validate(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsRSA.rsaSignTest(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsRSA.(Unknown Source)\n\tat java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)\n\tat java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.loadClass(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.access$200(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus$Loader.(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsDRBG$Builder.(Unknown Source)\n\tat org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsDRBG$Base.fromEntropySource(Unknown Source)\n\tat com.jivesoftware.ps.addons.custom.sso.api.SamlApi.sso(SamlApi.java:101)

Please help.

Comment: Have you modified the jar in any way?

Comment: The module has been modified.

Comment: How could I have done that mistakenly?

Comment: e.g. by repackaging it with other code into a single jar file, or perhaps running any sort of obfuscation tool on it. In any case, just locate the physical jar the code is coming from and ensure it is identical to the original.

Comment: Isn't all code packed into a single jar? I have specified bc-fips as a dependency in my pom file and importing it into my Java src file for use.

Comment: Did you ever find out what to do here?  This is happening for me too. I want a fat jar though.  This is dumb

Comment: No I had to switch to JKS :/